# Does ninhydrin staining detect triethylamine?

Tags: chromatography

My reaction mixture has amine compounds, so it shows tailing in bare silica plates. Therefore I decided to add small amount of triethylamine in the eluent. Because my amine compound is not detected by UV, I used ninhydrin staining. But something went wrong. The whole plate turned purple. I tried spot only triethylamine in the plate, dipped into ninhydrin solution, and heated it. The purple color showed. What is the problem? Doesn't ninhydrin only detect the amines which have N-H bond? Searching for this problem, I found that staining with ninhydrin shortly after eluting with 1% triethylamine is one of [rookie mistakes in TLC](http://www.chem.rochester.edu/notvoodoo/pages/rookie_mistakes.php?page=tlc). But how can the ninhydrin detect triethylamine which is a tertiary amine?

Comment: Judging from your previous question, you did not seem to have this problem before: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/164299/tlc-monitoring-of-buchwald-hartwig-coupling-reaction-using-ninhydrin-stain.

Comment: @Snijderfrey That's right. The impurity issue is convincing, but I am considering another reasons just in case. Also I feel mysterious triethylamine is detected with ninhydrin although it wasn't about two weeks ago.

Comment: Please edit to include such info in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that tertiary amines like triethylamine will not react with ninhydrin in the typical thin layer chromatography (TLC) staining conditions. However, when you use triethylamine *as received* it will not be 100 % pure. Triethylamine is prepared by alkylation of ammonia. As a result, it usually contains small residues of ammonia and partially alkylated derivatives. These can react with ninhydrin, giving a stained TLC plate. Therefore, I suspect that what you see results from impurities in your triethylamine.

Since you did not have the problem before in one of your previous questions ([TLC monitoring of Buchwald-Hartwig coupling reaction using ninhydrin stain](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/164299/tlc-monitoring-of-buchwald-hartwig-coupling-reaction-using-ninhydrin-stain)), impurities may also have been introduced in the meantime by uncareful usage of the bottle.

Comment: Seems probable if ammonia is formed during storage after purchase. But in the website I linked, it is written that staining with ninhydrin shortly after eluting with 1% TEA is common mistakes. I think the website is saying that there is another problem other than the impurities. Is the staining 'shortly' after eluting problem?

Comment: It takes a while for triethylamine to evaporate, the same is true for its impurities (and the other solvents you use).